# Is full text search suitable for searching people's names?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a user table with a single column for a person's name:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    Id bigint NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(80) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC)
)
```

The `Name` column can contain either a full name or just the first name or anything really (separated by spaces). In order to implement a search on `Name`, I would like to utilize SQL's full-text search, but not sure if it's suitable for searching names/nicknames and not actual words. Also the question is - which language do I choose when creating the FT index on `Name`?

Any other considerations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that if you want to search multi-part names, full-text search is the easiest and most appropriate approach (please correct me if I'm wrong). The other alternative being `LIKE '%query%'`, however it has too many disadvantages:

- Terrible performance, since it does index scan
- Order of terms matters, e.g. - searching for "John Smith" and "Smith John" will return different results.
- It disregards word boundaries, e.g. - searching for "Ann" will also retrieve "Joanna" and "Danny", which aren't useful matches.

So I went ahead and implemented a full-text search. My queries look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '"John*"')
```

The only slight difficulty is that I had to convert user query (John) into a CONTAINS-friendly query ("John*"). To do that, I implemented this method in my UserRepository:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts user-entered search query into a query that can be consumed by CONTAINS keyword of SQL Server.
/// </summary>
/// <example>If query is "John S Ju", the result will be "\"John*\" AND \"S*\" AND \"Ju*\"".</example>
/// <param name="query">Query entered by user.</param>
/// <returns>String instance.</returns>
public static string GetContainsQuery(string query)
{
    string containsQuery = string.Empty;

    var terms = query.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    if (terms.Length > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < terms.Length; i++)
        {
            string term = terms[i].Trim();

            // Add wildcard term, e.g. - "term*". The reason to add wildcard is because we want
            // to allow search by partially entered name parts (partially entered first name and/or
            // partially entered last name, etc).
            containsQuery += "\"" + term + "*\"";

            // If it's not the last term.
            if (i < terms.Length - 1)
            {
                // We want all terms inside user query to match.
                containsQuery += " AND ";
            }
        }

        containsQuery = containsQuery.Trim();
    }
    else
    {
        containsQuery = "\"" + query + "*\"";
    }

    return containsQuery;
}
```

Hope this helps anyone stumbling into the same issue.

PS - I wrote a [blogpost](http://22bugs.tumblr.com/post/36262552664/searching-peoples-names-with-sql-server-full-text) documenting this.

Comment: What if database contains errors. For example names are misspelled. I think your solution wouldnt work if you have an entry in database with name 'Jhn Somename'. Using your solution probably wouldn't find this entry with apropriate select. Is it possible to perform full text search with searching for similart (not exactly the same) names?

Answer (score 4):

At first sight, I would recommend using the LIKE operator rather than a full-text query.

Make sure you search case insensitive and probably accent insensitive. This can be achieved by the setting the correct collation on either the server, database, the table column or in your query. In the query, this is done by something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Users]
WHERE Name LIKE '%niaher%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
```

If you use a full-text index, you get all sorts of features, like verb stemming and thesaurus, see [Linguistic Components and Language Support in Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx#components), which you do not need, when searching in a list of names. By the way, these features are language dependent and that's why you specify a language on the full-text index.

Application of a stoplist you might even want to avoid. At least I would, since in Dutch many surnames start with articles and/or prepositions: "Rembrandt **van** Rijn". "van" would be in a Dutch stoplist for sure and prevent any match on a search term that contains "van".

If you run into performance issues, it might be useful to try a full-text index and search using [CONTAINS with a simple term](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx#sectionToggle5).

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Users]
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, 'niaher')
```

Please note that full-text indexes are updated asynchronously.

Comment: R. Schreurs, thank you for your answer. I have decided to go with the full-text search, because simple LIKE '%query%' has too many downsides, first being performance.